# Ubuntu won't start after closing laptop lid

Tags: suspend, laptop, power-management, shutdown

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on a Dell latitude e6430 laptop. Whenever I close my laptop lid or sometimes when I lock the screen before shutting the lid, when I open the lid again Ubuntu won't pull up the lock screen. The screen will be off, and I have to force shut down my laptop before rebooting. How can I fix this?

Comment: Maybe another case of not having enough swap space set up to enable the Suspend feature? See if the "Setting up your swap for Suspend" answer, found in [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/937454/whenever-i-close-my-laptop-lid-my-computer-crashes) answers your question.