# Whenever I close my laptop lid my computer crashes

Tags: suspend, power-management, shutdown, laptop, acpi

Every time I close the laptop lid, press the power button, shut down the computer or restart it, it's freezing (SysReq+REISUB doesn't help either).

When I'm on a terminal only TTY and close the lid I get following kernel messages:

```
wlp20f0: deauthenticating from XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING
pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: BAR 14: no space for [mem size 0x00200000]
pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: BAR 14: failed to assign [mem size 0x00200000 64bit pref]
```

followed by many other lines basically repeating the last two messages just with other addresses. `wlp20f0` is my WiFi device which works just fine. This WiFi related message only comes when closing the lid.

This happens on Linux 4.10 as well as on 4.11. The problem is present since I have Ubuntu 17.04 installed.
The Laptop is a HP 250-G3.

---

The last message I get when trying to shut the laptop down is:

```
[ OK ] Reached target Shutdown
```

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution to my problem.
I just had to add `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="acpi=force"` and now it works like I expect it to work.

**EDIT**
This just got rid of the freezing when closing the lid for a short time. Having it closed for a longer time or pressing the power button still let's my laptop freeze. However I hope that this method helps others in similar situations.